# Join two tables, put conditions to create new columns and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to do next:

I have a table made from two tables. The script is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    L.LSCRV, C.POSIC_ACTUAL, 
    C.IMP_CMA, C.LIMIT
FROM 
    ADC.RV L 
LEFT JOIN 
    ADC.CCB C ON SUBSTR(L.CLIENT, 1, 12) = C.CLIENT
```

I want now to add some conditions in order to create new column named CONDITION

```
case when C.POSIC_ACTUAL = '10' then 1 else 0 end 
as CONDITION
```

And finally I want to group by LSCRV and CONDITION

The output table should appear with that columns:

```
LSCRV    CONDITION    sum(IMP_CMA) as IMP     sum(LIMITE) as LIM  Count(*) 
as Clients
```

How could I do that?

Thanks

The joined table appears like that

```
CLIENT    LSCRV   POSIC_ACTUAL   IMP_CMA    LIMIT
479        A         010         2253.75    601.01
352        A         010            1200    3300
352        B         020               0    0
352        A         040               0    0
419        C         010            2600    600
019        C         042               0    0
```

The otuput table should appear like that:

```
LSCRV     CONDITION     IMP_CMA      LIMITE     CLIENTS
  A            1         3453.75     3901.01       2
  A            0            0           0          1
  B            0            0           0          1
  C            1          2600         600         1
  C            0            0           0          1
```

Comment: Strange join condition. What kind of client column data do you have? Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (All as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Sql Oracle is the DBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your explanation

```
SELECT LSCRV, CONDITION, 
      sum(IMP_CMA) as IMP, 
      sum(LIMITE) as LIM, 
      Count(*) as Clients 
      FROM (
                SELECT L.LSCRV,
                case when C.POSIC_ACTUAL = '10' then 1 else 0 end as CONDITION,  --- this will check your case condition
                C.IMP_CMA, C.LIMIT
                FROM ADC.RV L LEFT JOIN ADC.CCB C
                     ON SUBSTR(L.CLIENT, 1,12) = C.CLIENT 
            ) 
      GROUP BY LSCRV , CONDITION  --- this will apply group by as you need
```

Comment: Working! Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this in SQL - Server..

```
 SELECT LSCRV,CONDITION,SUM(IMP_CMA) AS IMP,SUM(LIMIT) AS LIM , COUNT(*) AS Clients 
 FROM (
 SELECT 
 case when C.POSIC_ACTUAL = '10' then 1 else 0 end 
 as CONDITION,LSCRV,IMP_CMA,LIMIT FROM (

 SELECT L.LSCRV, C.POSIC_ACTUAL, 
 C.IMP_CMA, C.LIMIT
 FROM ADC.RV L LEFT JOIN ADC.CCB C
 ON SUBSTRING(L.CLIENT, 1,12) = C.CLIENT ) AS A) AS B GROUP BY LSCRV,CONDITION
```